# Mapbox GL JS disable scroll zoom

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Unable to disable the default zooming on scroll functionality on Mapbox GL JS. Nothing in the API documentation sheds light on this. Even missing the scroll event in their docs.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
  zoom: 15
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspected the map object, saw the `scrollZoom` and tried to call the disable. Great success!

```
map.scrollZoom.disable();
```

Comment: Deprecated. Use map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

Answer (score 11):

Or in another way:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
    zoom: 15,
    scrollZoom      : false,
    boxZoom         : false,
    doubleClickZoom : false
});
```

Comment: In addition, use the "keyboard: false" option to disable the keyboard zoom with + / - keys